# Common animation / physics equation repository

Tags: language-agnostic, animation, physics, easing, equation-solving

For some time, I've been on the lookout for some type of centralized, online repository of commonly used animation / physics equations. Its easy enough to load up some physics framework like [Box2d](http://www.box2d.org/) and call it a day, but I'm looking for a source that is a little less abstract.

Ideally, this would be a language-agnostic catalog of mathmatical formulas *and* their programmatic implementation, and would be associated with a specific motion problem. For example: how to control an object that is ejected from a catapult, or perhaps a self-powered projectile, like a rocket. Or simply how to describe orbital motion around a central body.

The closest type of sources that I've found are things like [Robert Penners easing equations](http://www.robertpenner.com/) (for old school flash), or [Jakobsons Advanced Character Physics](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEEQFjAG&url=http://www.cs.unc.edu/~lin/COMP259-S03/PAPERS/verlet.doc&rct=j&q=verlet%20programming%20hitman&ei=81ADTpetIObTiALHyKWDDg&usg=AFQjCNEJjrux2zGF1U4iS7U30cbXe0YluQ&sig2=gydTeXq5fpm_ArlvXBVGVg) document. But these are, of course, limited in scope. I'm trying to get at something much more comprehensive, and not necessarily game-specific.

Yes, I generally don't have to look too hard to find such answers on a case by case basis, but a centralized source would be most excellent.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm. Nothing? Perhaps I should make one. Anyone interested in helping on a cool side project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many physics and animation equations and algorithms that a single comprehensive source would be impossibly large and not something any one person could write. Something more manageable would be a list of sources that address the details you want on specific topics. For example [Kenny Erleben's thesis on Multibody Dynamics](ftp://ftp.diku.dk/diku/image/publications/erleben.050401.pdf) or [Micky Kelager's paper on fluid dynamics using SPH](http://image.diku.dk/projects/media/kelager.06.pdf) both give the physical formulas and in depth practical implementations for their respective topics.

Comment: Well = I think this is the correct answer, in so far as its probably the reason why something like this doesn't exist. But i still think its a good idea ;) And it definitely is too large for a single person to work on, but setting up a community site for a project like this is, I think, reasonable. Again - *commonly used* would be the main idea - so not necessarily *comprehensive*, per se. At any rate - cheers!